# How to get network delta receives and network delta sends for a process on Windows?

Tags: windows, winapi, network-programming, process-explorer

On Windows, the Sysinternals process explorer can show the network delta receives & sends. How can I get this information with Windows API? Are there any libraries or frameworks (no matter what programming language it uses) for me to get this information?

[image]

Comment: Why vote to close? Is there anything unclear about the question? You shouldn't vote to close just because you don't know the answer or you don't like the question.

Comment: I suggest you could try to use [GetTcpStatistics function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-gettcpstatistics?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to retrieve the TCP statistics for the local computer. And you could also try to use [Win32_PerfFormattedData_Tcpip_NetworkInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//aa394293(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) to make an inquiry.